# os.read(0,) vs sys.stdin.buffer.read() in python

Tags: python, stdin

I encountered the [picotui](https://github.com/pfalcon/picotui) library, and was curious to know a bit how it works.

I saw [here](https://github.com/pfalcon/picotui/blob/master/picotui/screen.py) (line 147) that it uses:

```
os.read(0,32)
```

According to Google 0 represents `stdin`, but also that the accepted answer for reading from stdin is via

```
sys.stdin.buffer.read()
```

I was wondering what the difference is between the two. Which is faster? Which is the more portable version?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `os.read(0, 32)` is an *unbuffered* read, directly invoking an OS-level syscall and reading only a very specific amount of data (with a firm guarantee that the individual call won't read more than that). Sometimes -- for example, if you're going to be handing off your stdin to a different program and letting *it*  read the rest of the pending data -- you specifically need that.

`sys.stdin.buffer.read()` is a *buffered* read (and, without specifying a length, one that reads as much as possible). A buffered read can potentially read more data that you're immediately asking for (even though it only *returns* the requested amount, keeping the rest in a buffer to use to handle future requests), to reduce the number of syscalls made and thus operate with lower context-switch overhead when reading lots of data (in particular, when you would otherwise be doing lots of short reads, buffering reduces the number of round-trips between userland and the OS kernel).

Which of these is appropriate is deeply dependent on implementation and runtime-envionment details, and a question asking which is appropriate for a given scenario would need to include more details to not be overbroad. **What's important is that you don't mix them**; performing an unbuffered read after a buffered read can have unpredictable results, since there's no way of knowing how much data was already read by the OS to populate as-yet-unused parts of the read buffer.

Comment: does os.read(0, 32) work cross platform? also, is sys.stdin.read(0,32) the same as  os.read(0, 32) on python 3?

Comment: The answers to your two questions are yes, and no, in that order. The first `0` is the FD number, so passing the `0` to `sys.stdin.read` makes no sense; the very identify of `sys.stdin` itself specifies the FD. Moreover, `sys.stdin.read` is not guaranteed to be an unbuffered syscall, whereas `os.read()` *is*.

Comment: Cheers. Any reason why one is in os and the other in sys?

Comment: `os` is where low-level syscall interfaces live, and is allowed to be incompatible across platforms (even though `read` in practice, AFAIK, shouldn't be; it's been around in UNIX long enough to have become pretty much universal). `sys` is where higher-level interfaces live.

Comment: How does sys.stdin.detach() fare against os.read? https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.detach

Comment: Perhaps you can help out with a `os.write()` [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502211/printing-a-font-icon-with-os-write)?

Comment: Not on Windows. I'm quite familiar with how terminals work on Unixlike operating systems, but Windows is a different beast.