# How Do You Make Timed Keyboard Responds?

Tags: python

I want to make it so that the game will print and ask to type a certain letter, and if I don't then I lose
What I want it to be like:
Press E:
(if you don't type it after 5 seconds, you lose. If you DO type it, the game will continue)

Comment: Maybe try `sys.stdin.buffer.read`, or just read stdin normally if you don't mind having a newline. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596557/os-read0-vs-sys-stdin-buffer-read-in-python)

Comment: Do you want to do this on the terminal, or in a GUI? I have a way to do it through the terminal but it's unix only and can potentially break the terminal (at least on my system). IO is only updated every newline, so bypassing that is extremely difficult unless you have it listen to the keypresses individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update: I have been told that this is a bad answer, so I decided to improve it, but I left in my old reply for you to still see*

##### Old reply:

Check out the keyboard library, and probably the time library too. I think the easiest way to do this is to create some sort of clock, save a "start time" (what time the prompt came up) and then enter a loop, exiting only when you have either pressed the key, or 5 seconds from the start time has elapsed. Make sure you keep track of which one actually happened.

##### My updated response, including a code example:

Okay so we're going to be using the `time` and `keyboard` libraries.

###### Note: In order to use most functions in `keyboard`, you need to run your script on root. You'll have to look up instructions if you're running a different OS, but what I did on my linux machine was just first installing keyboard on root (idk why it needed to be installed seprately but it did) with `sudo pip install keyboard`, and then running my code as `sudo python3 filename.py`

.

Our code is going to be running all within a while loop. Here's the basic idea:

```
play = True
while play:
    play = runGame('e')
```

where `runGame()` is a func that plays 1 "round" of the game, and returns True if you win, False if you lose.

First, let's look at a way to actually tell if we pressed some desired key (like 'e') We'll be using `keyboard.on_press_key()` We'll be passing 2 arguments into it, `key` (what key will trigger it) and `callback` (a function to call when that key gets pressed) see [the docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.on_press_key) for more info.

So something like this:

```
import keyboard

def keyIsPressed(x):
    global buttonPress
    buttonPress = True

# calls keyIsPressed() when we press targetKey
keyboard.on_press_key(targetKey, keyIsPressed)
```

i added the unused `x` argument in the function because `on_press_key` wants to return some data into the function when you use it. Feel free to `print(x)` to get a look at what that data is. I just did that as an easy way to deal with an error.

Okay, so let's put everything together finally:

```
import keyboard
import time

#func called by on_press_key when our targetKey is pressed
def keyIsPressed(x):
    global buttonPress
    buttonPress = True

def runGame(targetKey):
    # variable to tell if we have pressed the targetKey yet
    global buttonPress
    # always start the round false
    buttonPress = False

    # calls keyIsPressed() when we press targetKey
    keyboard.on_press_key(targetKey, keyIsPressed)

    #start time
    st = time.time()
    while True:
        #current time
        ct = time.time()

        # if 5 seconds or more has passed between start time and current time
        if ct >= (st + 5):
            print("you took too long!")
            return buttonPress      #False

        #if you have pressed the button
        elif buttonPress:
            #unhook the key now that you're done with it
            keyboard.unhook_key(targetKey)

            print("\n\nwow u did it good job!\n\n")
            return buttonPress      #True

# Run
buttonPress = False
play = True
# you don't have to use a list, but I'm doing so for my prototype
letters = ['e', 'f', 'g']
#the amount of times you've played
loops = 0

while play:
    # play the game, use 'e', then 'f', then 'g'
    # outside of a prototype, you'll need to update the list or use a different
    # method to avoid errors after 3 rounds
    play = runGame(letters[loops])
    #up loop counter
    loops += 1

#remove all key hooks when you are done playing
keyboard.unhook_all()
```

Hopefully that's comprehensive enough without being too wordy. I really wasn't expecting this to be as difficult as it was, but all of the intuitive solutions that I thought of actually ran into issues either with dropping inputs, or freezing the loop. So this is the simplest implementation I could come up with.

Comment: I've come back to this and decided to actually put in the work. I added a new response, put in a full code prototype, and hopefully that should work for OP now.